# IntelliJ double click in Project view on class with internal classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

IntelliJ double click in Project view on class with internal classes opens the node in the Projects view or closes the node in the Project view if it was open. I can't figure out to change the settings of IntelliJ so that if I double click on a class it opens the class in the editor. It works fine for normal classes, but if the class has embedded internal classes defined, IntelliJ does not jump to the class, but opens the node in the Projects view.

There must be a setting to override this?

Comment: Same issue, it's more annoying in Kotlin cause it opens the node down to the members/fields before it opens the class file in editor.

Comment: Did anyone figure out the solution, facing same issue and its very annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you should switch off Show Members option in your project menu
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Open Files with Single Click" setting will, at least with Kotlin, open the selected file in the editor without expanding the node. Not exactly the requested behavior, but may be a workaround for some.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure on what you're asking here but hazarding a guess:

Showing internal classes in the Projects View you'd click the little cog on the bar at the top of the Projects View to open the drop down settings.
Then ensure "Show Members" is checked.

**OR**

If you're asking how to to "Jump to Source", hit F4.

Otherwise, hit "Ctrl + Alt + S" and hunt through IntelliJ's settings.

Answer (score -1):

Dock Pinned should be enabled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OMCO.png)